# I need help changing sticky add to cart button text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Thank you'll for contributing to this amazing comunity

I spent a long time and got a massive headache trying everything I know and searched to **change the add to cart text on this plugin** I use called Simple sticky add to cart

Can anyone help me get this to work, I highly appreciate it
here is a demo

https://solbox.dev/demo-sticky/product/motorcycle-repair-shop-dark-teal-printed-tshirt/

Thank you in advance

Comment: Paste your code rather than a link to it.

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with coding, so I do not really know what code I should paste, this screenshot must help https://i2.paste.pics/DNUCO.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );                // < 2.1
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );  // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {

    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Comment: thank you Rajeev Singh for providing the code

Comment: however, it only changed the main woocommerce add to cart text                           what I am dealing with here is another plugin that has a separate sticky add to cart button as I mentioned in the first thread, please take a look at this screenshot https://i2.paste.pics/DNUCO.png

Comment: It's working with woocommerce plugin. if you are using another plugin also, so in that case override another plugin templates and change button text.

Comment: How to override: create plugin same name folder inside our active themes folder and copy plugin template/file from your plugin folder and paste inside your newly created folder within the theme folder.